# How I can find duplicate and add row number/Count

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to iterate an array of objects and wants to add the count for the objects. only count once for the unique once. and want to find the duplicated one count as well.

I have an Input like this:

```
var users = [
      { user: 'barney', age: 36 },
      { user: 'barney', age: 36 },
      { user: 'travis', age: 37 },
      { user: 'alex',   age: 40 },
      { user: 'paige',  age: 33 },
      { user: 'paige',  age: 33 },
];
```

I want output like this:

```
var users = [
      { user: 'barney', age: 36, count: 1 },
      { user: 'barney', age: 36, count: 2 },
      { user: 'travis', age: 37, count: 1 },
      { user: 'alex',   age: 40, count: 1 },
      { user: 'paige',  age: 33, count: 1 },
      { user: 'paige',  age: 33, count: 2 },
];
```

Comment: So if there was another user `paige` in the first row, then first `paige` has count `1`, and n-1 has count `2` and last one has count `3`. Isn't it? (Then, just for my curiosity, why do you need this?) Thank you for your clarification!

Comment: @ValerioBozz yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `map` to store `count` state for each item,

```js
let map = {};

var users = [
  { user: 'barney', age: 36},
  { user: 'barney',  age: 36 },
  { user: 'travis', age: 37},
  { user: 'alex', age: 40},
  { user: 'paige', age: 33},
  { user: 'paige', age: 33}
];

var result = users.map(v => {
  var item = v.user + "." + v.age;
  map[item] ??= 0;
  map[item]++;
  return { ...v, count: map[item] }
});

console.log(result)
```